# Seller Cloud service reference in visual studio needs reference update for ever release

Tags: c#, soap, visual-studio-2015, wsdl, service-reference

I have a service reference to seller cloud using WSDL to get the orders. The problem I am facing right now is whenever seller cloud update their SOAP API version (which they often do), my project reference becomes obsolete and it stops getting the orders from the API and throws an error 'Unknown exception occurred'.
The service reference works just fine when I update it. I wanted to know if there is a way to auto update the service reference to the latest version or any other solution that doesn't break the service reference SOAP API update.

Comment: Does the seller cloud make same changes every update or are the errors random errors?  You can't be a mind-reader and predict what the seller is going to change in the future if they are random errors.

Comment: @jdweng no they don't have errors because when I update the service reference it works fine.

Comment: Can you make the service reference a config item so you do not have to compile? Just change the configuration.